# Materialize drop downs won't drop on hover

Tags: meteor, materialize

For whatever reason, my Materialize drop down menus won't drop on hover (they should be default).

```
<ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance" id="camp-dates">CAMP DATES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance" id="prices">CAMP PRICES</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance"  id="finance-webhooks">STRIPE FORMS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance"  id="update-forms">UPDATE FORMS</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="dropdown4" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance" id="camp-dates">CAMP DATES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance" id="prices">CAMP PRICES</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="dropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance"  id="finance-webhooks">STRIPE FORMS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance"  id="update-forms">UPDATE FORMS</a></li>
</ul>

<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">&nbsp; ACCOUNTING</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down hlight">
            <li><a href="#" class="bold-only" id="pay-by-check">CHECK PAYMENT</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-button bold-only" href="#" data-activates="dropdown2">SETTINGS<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-button bold-only" href="#" data-activates="dropdown1">WEBHOOKS<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bold-only" id="tuition-reports">REPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bold-only" id="finance-charts">CHARTS</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="#" id="pay-by-check">CHECK PAYMENT</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="dropdown4">SETTINGS<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="dropdown3">WEBHOOKS<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="tuition-reports">REPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="finance-charts">CHARTS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've got the dropdown initialized (I'm in Meteor so initializing would be inside an onRendered Template):

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
}
```

So my thought was to see if I could force it with some CSS (one of my weaknesses):

```
.nav-wrapper ul.hlight li:hover #dropdown2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Arg. This is wrong. Can I force this in CSS if the default isn't working? Right now my version of Meteor is using jQuery 1.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic approach do not work with Materialize CSS because it has its own JavaScript methods.

Define `dropdown-button` & `dropdown-content` in your template like:

```
<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance" id="camp-dates">CAMP DATES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hover-nav-finance" id="prices">CAMP PRICES</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then on client-side JavaScript initiate it like:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
          inDuration: 300,
          outDuration: 225,
          constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
          hover: true, // Activate on hover
          gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
          belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
          alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
        }
      );
}
```

Now on hover, it will drop because you defined: `hover: true, // Activate on hover`

I think you missed `dropdown-button` part.

For more information: http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try later today when I've got the time and report back.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the only thing you've added was the object inside the dropdown() function. I had tried, a few days ago, inserting { hover: true } and it didn't work. Inserting all of the options doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @MatthewMoon Don't forget to add `<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>` part to your template.

Comment: @MatthewMoon I can't see it in the code that you have share with us in your question. Please update your question if you have updated your code.

Comment: Inside the <div class="nav-wrapper"> in the first <ul>, the second and third <li>'s are the triggers, the first one being: <li><a class="dropdown-button bold-only" href="#" data-activates="dropdown2">SETTINGS<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>. Unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: @MatthewMoon There is not even a `ul.dropdown-content` class inside your `<nav>` tag! You have to stick with the exact order and exact class names that I gave you in my answer. Materialize CSS will work properly if and only if you use exact class names in your template.

Comment: I see you're following the dropdown button format from Materialize. I'm using the dropdown nav. See http://materializecss.com/navbar.html Just to test, I put a dropdown button on the page following your (and according to the dropdown button html from Materialize) and it still doesn't drop on hover.

Comment: @MatthewMoon Open http://materializecss.com/navbar.html on your browser(mine is *Chrome*). Open *Developer tools > Console* and execute `$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({...}` part of my answer from Google Chrome's console. See if it works or not, for me it works. I recommend you to achieve this feature with a minimal example of *navbar*. Later make your edit on it.

Comment: I'm able to get it to work on the materialize site using the console, but trying a minimal example of navbar or a dropdown button in my app is proving unsuccessful. I'm seeing if there's a conflict in my CSS somewhere. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in the Materialize package for Meteor with some of the drop downs. The latest update has issues evidently so it shouldn't be installed yet.

Comment: @MatthewMoon Could you share a link to the issue. I'm aware that Materialize CSS's maintenance is not that good lately. As a last word, I recommend to try minimal example with a clean Meteor App (created with `meteor create myapp`) so you can see if there is a conflict or not.

Comment: This isn't a direct link to the issue itself, but there's a mention on the latest release of materialize:materialize on atmosphere.com that it fixes a drop down bug https://atmospherejs.com/materialize/materialize. I did uninstall the atmosphere package and install the nom version instead and it worked fine, but my problem is that I can't use the nom version without a lot of refactoring because I use a modal package that seems to only work with the atmosphere version. The new atmosphere version has issues here https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3863

Comment: @MatthewMoon I do not understand exactly what is the issue. Please don't let your question tagged as unanswered if my answer is good enough. I'm happy if I could be able to help you even a tiny bit. Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for your time and patience. You helped me considerably.